# PyTest and DeleteView

Tags: django-views, pytest

I'm trying to test a very basic DeleteView. My problem is that the view request doesn't delete the object and it doesn't return a 200 or 204. The view and model code are very basic. Usually it's a 302.

**[Update]**: I read through the Django unit test (django/tests/generic_views/test_edit.py) and it does return a 302. But I still can't get it to actually delete the object.

Here's the code:

```py
import pytest

from django.urls import reverse
from factory import DjangoModelFactory
from pytest_factoryboy import register

from ..models import Product
from ..views import ProductDeleteView


@register
class ProductFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Product


@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestProductView:
    def test_delete_product(self, client, django_user_model, product_factory):
        test_user = django_user_model.objects.create(
                      username = 'username',
                      password = 'password',
                      is_superuser = True,
                      is_staff = True
                    )
        product = product_factory(
                    name = 'widget'
                  )
        client.login(username = 'username', password = 'password')
        print(Product.objects.all())
        response = client.post(reverse('delete_product', args = (product.pk,)))
        print(Product.objects.all())

        assert response.status_code == 302
        assert list(Product.objects.all()) == list(Product.objects.none())


# model code:

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# url code:

path(
    route    = 'product-delete/<int:pk>/',
    view     = ProductDeleteView.as_view(),
    name     = 'delete_product'),

# view code:

class ProductDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'empty.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy(viewname = 'home')
```

Comment: add `ProductDeleteView` code

Comment: I added the model, url and view code. I also changed the args in the response line in the test code from id to pk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doctest-based Django unit test uses client.post with a URL and I couldn't find a way to use this technique with pytest. But I can use the RequestFactory fixture to format a request, associate the request with a user and then send the request with the view:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestProductView:
    def test_delete_product(self, rf, client, django_user_model, product_factory):
        test_user = django_user_model.objects.create(
                      username = 'username',
                      password = 'password',
                      is_superuser = True,
                      is_staff = True
                    )
        product = product_factory(
                    name = 'widget'
                  )
        client.login(username = 'username', password = 'password')
        request         = rf.post(
                               reverse(
                                 viewname  = 'delete_product',
                                 kwargs    = { 'pk': product.pk }
                               )
                             )
        request.user    = test_user
        response        = ProductDeleteView.as_view()(request, **{ 'pk': product.pk })

        assert response.status_code == 302
        assert list(Product.objects.all()) == list(Product.objects.none())
```